# Barcode scanning stops showing Messagebox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, barcode

I am working on a desktop application in c# with a barcode scanning module. The problem is that whenever I scan a barcode the application stops showing Messageboxes. Application does ot throw any exception, it just executes the code.

Application works perfectly before scanning a barcode.

I have no idea why is this happening and how do I solve it.

This is my code:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BarcodeScan) && e.KeyChar.ToString() == "*")
   BarcodeScan = e.KeyChar.ToString();

else if (Regex.IsMatch(BarcodeScan + e.KeyChar.ToString(), @"^[*]\d+$"))
   BarcodeScan += e.KeyChar.ToString();

else if (Regex.IsMatch(BarcodeScan + e.KeyChar.ToString(), @"^[*]\d+[*]$"))
{
   BarcodeScan += e.KeyChar.ToString();
   ArticalID = BarcodeScan.Substring(1, BarcodeScan.Length - 2);

   //Code to find article in DB

   ArticalID = string.Empty;
   BarcodeScan = string.Empty;
}
else
{
   if (BarcodeScan.StartsWith("*"))
   {
        BarcodeScan = string.Empty;
   }
}
```

Comment: How about showing us some code...?

Comment: ...and does your barcode reader device have any SDK or is it just dumb keyboard-emulator?

Comment: @StaWho this is a dumb keyboard-emulator.

Comment: how do you tell when the barcode has been read? Is it `textbox.TextChanged`? If that's the case @Fischermaen may have a point and your inbound string contains new line character or something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your question: a barcode scanner sends the scanned numbers / characters mostly with an "Enter" at the end. Maybe that enter closes your MessageBox by invoking the default button.

Comment: hmmm I think you have got a point, this could be the reason. Let me check it. If this is true how do I tackle the issue. Actually I show an alert when the scanned ID is not found in our db.

Comment: sorry for late update, i got busy in other tasks. You are right the issue is due to 2 enters passed by the barcode reader. I tried to refactor my code but could not find a solution. Could you please help me fix my code? The format to scan is *Digits*, I cannot test for *Digits*\n\n because the user can enter the same format with keyboard as well.

Comment: @Haris You may want to see if you have the option of changing the behavior of the barcode provider. If you have a barcode "gun" that's just emulating a keyboard, consult the manual and see if you can change the behavior. I've worked with Wasp scanners before and they were highly configurable.