# Barcode scanning closes MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode-scanner

I'm creating a desktop application with barcode scanner module to read the barcode and when the article has been found in my db, it prints out the detail. After printing, it shows a dialog message to confirm if the print has been successfully done or not!

When I try to enter the barcode manually using the keyboard(ex. *1220*) it works perfectly and the dialog will show up, but when I use barcode scanner, the dialog disappears!

I tried to duplicate the message box and I find out that an extra event is happening and it closes the first message box and shows the second one!

Here is the question: How can I prevent the extra event when I use the barcode scanner?

I found this similar link [Barcode scanning stops showing Messagebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604130/barcode-scanning-stops-showing-messagebox) but it didn't work for me!

Any ideas?

Comment: Some codes snipet would be helpful !

Comment: Does the barcode scanner send an Enter as last character?

Comment: You found the link of a possibly duplicate question, but you mention it didn't work - what have you tried that didn't work? Also can you manually enter 1220 with the keyboard and then (also manually) hit enter to reproduce the error?

Comment: I am unsure how much you have worked with barcode scanners, but a scanner really is a keyboard, so if you scan the barcode in notepad and copy/paste everything into the textfield it should act the same.

Answer (score 0):

to remove the **Enter** after scan:
[image]

to add the **Tab** after scan:
[image]

More information can be found in the product User's Guide